# mach_port_insert_member_trap - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

All of a sudden when I enable breakpoints on Xcode it stops at

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`_kernelrpc_mach_port_insert_member_trap
```

I restarted Xcode, nothing happened. When I turn off breakpoints my app runs as usual.

If I step down the call stack into UIApplicationMain, the breakpoint is just below

```
symbol stub for: -[_UIHostedTextServiceSession dismissTextServiceAnimated:]
```

Does anyone know what this is?